# How do i use map() for errors with RxJava2?

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java

I am designing a function that will allow to check Internet connection on an Android device. I decided to use a reactive approach to implement it.
The function works really nice and is pretty simple: It just tries to resolve IP for the backend, and returns `false` if the DNS request failed, and `true` on success.
Here is the code of the function:

```
fun isConnectedToInternet(): Single<Boolean> {
        // Just check whether we can resolve IP for our target API endpoint
        return Single
            .defer{Single.just(InetAddress.getByName(API_URL).toString())}
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            // Trick to map an error to just a false value
            .onErrorReturnItem("Error")
            .map { it != "Error" }
    }
```

The question is whether the last two lines are considered as a good practice and if it isn't what is a correct option to do what I want in a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is pretty ok but if I were you I'd write like that:

```
fun isConnectedToInternet(): Single<Boolean> {
    // Just check whether we can resolve IP for our target API endpoint
    return Completable
        .fromCallable { InetAddress.getByName(API_URL) }
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .toSingle { true }
        .onErrorReturnItem(false)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This conversion from Completable to Single with changing value on error looks more beautiful as for me, but it is a little less straightforward.  Anyway, I think this is what I needed